# Why copy within or upload to ES File Explorer rename php file as txt?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, file-management, ftp

I am using ES File Explorer FTP service to upload php scripts, to be used with a web server on my android device.
I noticed all php files get renamed with .txt suffix, which make them unsuable.
Files with another extension do not seem to be affected.
This problem only occurs when copying or upload to extSdCard, on a non-rooted device, but allowed by a permission workaround.

Is it a bug? How could I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

i guess that is a bug but you may use bulk rename utility

Section 1:
match: (.*).txt
replace: \1

section 11
remove

Section 12:
filter: *.php.txt

hope it helps

Comment: It doesn't help. Even if you do this, according to the OP it will just get renamed again.

Comment: sorry about that... here we go
regEx (1)
match (.*).txt
replace \1
include ext
---------------------------
extension (11)
remove
-------------------------
selections
filter *.php.txt
match case unchecked